# how to migrate visual studio C# app to monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have an existing application developed using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 C#. I just purchased Xamarin's Monotouch product which allows me to use their IDE MonoDev to create iPhone/iPad applications from scratch by coding C#. Right now I don't want to code a new application. I want take my existing C# application import the source into monodev/monotouch and have the result run on the iPhone/iPad. My existing C# application is designed for deployment on Android phones/tablets using Xamarin's Android product. It works great! I have begun wading into the Xamarin documentation, samples, tutorials etc. But I need to port the existing application to iPhone/iPad right now, right away. I really don't have the luxery to spend time learning from scratch. I've got to belive someone has already gone down this migration path. If you have can we talk, email, or do you know if there is a guide describing the specific steps to take to accomplish this?
TIA

Comment: I'm sorry but you can't expect to deliver an app without learning the platform. Xamarin makes the transition easier but you still have to learn some iOS. And this is good.

Answer (score 5):

Xamarin MonoTouch does not allow you to run any C# application and run it immediately on an iPhone. The UI layer is native, so the C# code that constructs the UI must use the Xamarin bindings onto the Apple UI APIs.

The 'standard' migration process is to create an empty MonoDevelop project then start adding your existing C# business logic files, resolving any compilation issues as they arise.